# If I delete a row with pandas, it remains in Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, save

If I delete a row with pandas, it remains in Excel

```
def sort_wickelfalzrohr(d):

    # Filter settings
    filt_with_isolation = (df_read['KZ'] == 'R-R') & (df_read['D'] == d) & (df_read['IsoOf'].isna() == False)
    filt_without_isolation = (df_read['KZ'] == 'R-R') & (df_read['D'] == d) & (df_read['IsoOf'].isna() == True) 


    # **delete sortet Elements in df_read**
    df_read.drop(index=df_read[filt_with_isolation].index, inplace=True)
    df_read.drop(index=df_read[filt_without_isolation].index, inplace=True)

    #print(df_read[filt_with_isolation])
    #print(df_read[filt_without_isolation])

sort_wickelfalzrohr(160)
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\tfern\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:36: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.

(6030.0, 41050.0)
```

If i search the deletet rows in pandas (after deleting it in the function sort_Wickelfalzrohr:

```
Output
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Nr, TsNr, ....
Index: []
```

But when I open the file, the row's are still there.
Do i have to save the file after the function?

[Code Jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxT1G.png)

Comment: Yes what's happening is expected. You have deleted the row from dataframe but not from excel. So, please write this dataframe into excel using `df.to_excel`. This will overwrite your existing excel with the new one which will not have that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. When you read from a file, you create a copy of the file in computer's memory. All the changes you make are in the memory, which will be deleted after you close the program. If you want to apply the changes to the file you should save your dataframe back to the file using `df.to_excel` or `df.to_csv` (if it was a csv file)